# UILabel will does not show up in collectionView Cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that will display a cell from the `dataArray`. The `dataArray` is changed to `self.postsArray` or `self.eventsArray` from a segmentControl as well as the reuseIdentifier to determine the cell(a post cell and a event cell). The events work fine, but the Post Cell, which contains a label with a tag of 95, does not work. When I `NSLog(@"label: %@", label);` I get nil. So i have no idea what the problem is.

```
#pragma mark Collection View:
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [dataArray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (dataArray == self.postsArray) {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:95];
    [label.text isEqualToString:@"Hello"];
    NSLog(@"label: %@", label);
    return cell;
}

if (dataArray == self.eventsArray) {
    PFObject *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIButton *eventButton = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSLog(@"Event: %@", eventButton);
    UIButton *groupButton = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:11];
    [eventButton setTitle:[temp objectForKey:@"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [groupButton setTitle:[temp objectForKey:@"Group_Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    eventButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    groupButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
return cell;
}


#pragma mark SegmentControl:
- (void) segmentChanged: (id) sender{
UISegmentedControl *seg = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    dataArray = self.postsArray;
    reuseIdentifier = @"postsCell";
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    dataArray = self.eventsArray;
    reuseIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you set the tag correctly in IB? If you log cell right after you log the label, does show the correct cell? If you select the second segment and then the first one, do you still get nil?

Comment: I logged cell after like you said and saw that `hidden == true`. I left `self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:groupReuseIdentifier]` in the viewDidLoad. Thanks @rdelmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:groupReuseIdentifier];` was left in my viewDidLoad and was hiding my first cells